# How to delay listeners in Android?

Tags: android, character, listener, drag, handwriting

I am trying to implement handwritten character recognition in Android.

My code has 3 Listeners: `onTouch`, `onDrag` and `onRemove` (So I can get the list of coordinates based on Drag Event). Since for some characters we need to lift up our finger for a small time (eg. for caps <kbd>K</kbd> or <kbd>H</kbd>, but in my case it's not English characters), but as soon as I lift up my finger from screen it calls remove listener, i want to delay the drag listener for few milliseconds, so that I can get the complete set of coordinates before calling remove listener. Is it possible to delay it, or is there any simple way to achieve this task?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I tried making your post a bit clearer, but I must say that it's still hard to understand. Please try to re-word it so that it's easy to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Right answer is not Timer, because it will create extra Thread to do simple thing. Because you mentioned

> delay the drag listener for **few milliseconds**

It's good to use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and postDelayed which takes Runnable/task you try to delay and long/delay timeout.

Comment: Let's say I have a surface view in which override `onTouch` Method is there. Till the time I am touching my view, I am getting set of coordinates in this session. As soon as I pull out my touch,  it starts new session, I want to delay this for few milliseconds and if I touch the view again within the delay, the next set of coordinates along with previous coordinates should come in single session. Is it possible?